# Need assistance in analyzing data (mean, median, mode, etc) from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am having difficulty with finding the mean, median, mode, counting occurrences of a value within a csv file.

This section of the file is a column of letters 'M' or 'F'

This specific excerpt of code displays a problem I am facing:

I am not sure why the counting variables are not being incremented. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
citations2 = open('Non Traffic Citations.csv')

data2 = csv.reader(citations2)

gender = []

for row in data2:
    gender.append(row[2])

del gender [0]

male_count = 0
female_count = 0

for item in gender:
    # print(item)   - shows that the list has values within it

    if 'M' == item:
        male_count = + 1
    if 'F' == item:
        female_count = + 1

print(male_count)
print(female_count)
```

Comment: Just need to swap the operators to be: `male_count += 1` and `female_count += 1`

Comment: Instead of `male_count = + 1` use` male_count += 1` and likewise for `female_count`. Also note you can use the built-in [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module to calculate several of the values you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to increment the gender counts, you have the syntax incorrect in your loop.

```
for item in gender:
   if 'F' == item:
      female_count += 1
   elif 'M' == item:
      male_count += 1

print(male_count)
print(female_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Non Traffic Citations.csv')
df.describe()
```